# Extracting data from a matlab struct in mex

Tags: matlab, struct, mex

I'm following [this example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-structures-and-cell-arrays.html) but I'm not sure what I missed. Specifically, I have this struct in MATLAB:

```
a = struct; a.one = 1.0; a.two = 2.0; a.three = 3.0; a.four = 4.0;
```

And this is my test code in MEX ---

First, I wanted to make sure that I'm passing in the right thing, so I did this check:

```
int nfields = mxGetNumberOfFields(prhs[0]);
mexPrintf("nfields =%i \n\n", nfields);
```

And it does yield `4`, since I have four fields.

However, when I tried to extract the value in field `three`:

```
tmp = mxGetField(prhs[0], 0, "three");
mexPrintf("data =%f \n\n",  (double *)mxGetData(tmp)  );
```

It returns `data =1.000000`. I'm not sure what I did wrong. My logic is that I want to get the first element (hence index is 0) of the field `three`, so I expected `data =3.00000`.

Can I get a pointer or a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**

Ok, since you didn't provide your full code but you are working on a test, let's try to make a new one from scratch.

On Matlab side, use the following code:

```
a.one = 1;
a.two = 2;
a.three = 3;
a.four = 4;

read_struct(a);
```

Now, create and compile the MEX `read_struct` function as follows:

```
#include "mex.h"

void read_struct(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    if (nrhs != 1)
        mexErrMsgTxt("One input argument required.");

    /* Let's check if the input is a struct... */
    if (!mxIsStruct(prhs[0]))
        mexErrMsgTxt("The input must be a structure.");

    int ne = mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[0]);
    int nf = mxGetNumberOfFields(prhs[0]);

    mexPrintf("The structure contains %i elements and %i fields.\n", ne, nf);

    mwIndex i;
    mwIndex j;

    mxArray *mxValue; 
    double *value;

    for (i = 0; i < nf; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < ne; ++j)
        {
            mxValue = mxGetFieldByNumber(prhs[0], j, i);
            value = mxGetPr(mxValue);

            mexPrintf("Field %s(%d) = %.1f\n", mxGetFieldNameByNumber(prhs[0],i), j, value[0]);
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Does this correctly prints your structure?

Comment: I tried the first suggestion and it was still giving me ```data =1.000000```. I can't try the second suggestion since it forces me to use an index. If not it gives me this error: error: no matching
function for call to 'mxGetFieldNumber'

Comment: How is what you're doing in the first suggestion different from my approach?

Comment: @MadPhysicist It yields an error though. Why can't I give ```prhs``` an index? I could have multiple inputs.

Comment: @trying. Comment rescinded. I didn't think it through. Could you post your full minimal mex function and the MATLAB code you use to set up and run it please?

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo Your example works. I just need to adapt it to my code. One question: why are you using ```mxGetPr``` instead of ```mxGetData```? I thought ```mxValue``` was already a pointer.